# Ractive Numeric For Loop Possible?

Tags: ractivejs

I've been looking at the docs, and can't seem to find a way to do the following:

```
   <script>
      var maxStars = 5 ;
   </script>

   <script id="starryNight" type="text/ractive">
     <ul class="starRating">
      {{#for i=0 until {{maxStars}} }}
          <li class="star"></li>
       {{/for}}
       </ul>
    </script>
```

The idea being to store numerically, how many stars an item has been given, e.g. in a shopping cart. Then draw the correct
number of stars for that item.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is converting the number into an iterable value.

You could go with the pedestrian:

```
 <ul class="starRating">
  {{#each Array(maxStars) }}
      <li class="star"></li>
  {{/each}}
 </ul>
```

Or go for something a bit more exciting by encapsulating the max stars in the iterable itself:

```
 <ul class="starRating">
  {{#each '★★★★★'.split('') }}
      <li class="star"></li>
  {{/each}}
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @martypdx! I will experiment with both ideas.

Comment: Very nice solution. Did exactly what you said. I went with your first option, since I didn't really follow how the second one would handle 'maxStars'. Thanks for taking the trouble to reply.